# Android: variable from String List returning always 0

Tags: android, string, textview

I'm trying to set a text in a `TextView` from a `List` of `Strings`. I can see the value in the `LogCat`, but when I put it in `TextView` I get 0. What could be the problem?

**EDIT My `List` is not empty, I can see values in the `LogCat`!!**

```
List<String> listResult = new ArrayList<String>();
// here i'm putting some data 
if (listResult != null)
{ 
    for (int i=0;i<listResult.size();i++)
    {
        Log.i("position",listResult.get(i)+"")//i can see the componnent of the list
        textView1.setText(position+1+"");
        textView3.setText(listResult.get(i)+"");//I'm getting 0
    }
    Log.i("*******","***************");
    Log.i("position",listResult+"")//i can see the whole list
}
```

This is the LogCat i'm getting :

```
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 2
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.970: I/position(21761): 6
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 2
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 4
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/position(21761): 0
05-20 11:39:07.971: I/*******(21761): ***************
05-20 11:39:07.972: I/position(21761): [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting 0 in `TextView` is that when you call `setText()` it sets a text replacing the one previously set, if any. So, in your case you just get the result of the last iteration, which is 0. In order to show the entire list in `TextView` you should add a new text to the one previously added at each iteration using [`append()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. The `for loop` should look as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i < listResult.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("position", listResult.get(i) + "")
    textView1.append(String.valueOf(position+1));
    textView3.append(listResult.get(i).toString() + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just initialized your `ArrayList`. There is nothing in your  `ArrayList`. After initialized you need to add element in your `ArrayList` like:

```
 listResult.add("text1");
 listResult.add("text2");
```

**Update:** try this way

```
 textView1.setText(position+1);
 textView3.setText(listResult.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over empty list (your code lacks `=` in that line):

```
List<String> listResult = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There's nothing in it, so all is fine.